# Netlogo library models error "Nothing named SIZE has been defined"

Tags: netlogo

I just started to work on `Netlogo`, and I am trying to learn how to use it. When I try to use Netlogo's own models most of them (For example : Party) gives me that notification "Nothing named SIZE has been defined" or "Nothing named HEADING has been defined".

My friend has the same program but his models work perfectly. The only difference he uses Windows 8, I use Windows 7.
*How can I fix that problem ?*

Comment: Just a guess, but... any chance you're using Windows in Turkish? https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/317

Comment: Really good guess and it is working now thanks to you.